# Find highest Value among duplicates in a table (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a table with duplicate values as shown below.

[image]

I would like to find the latest start time among the events. Expected output is

[image]

I used the below query but it seems to get the latest start time in the entire table.

```
SELECT ID,
EVENT,
START_TIME,
LAST_VALUE(START_TIME) OVER (ORDER BY ID,EVENT RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS latest_start_time
FROM
(Select * from EVENTS)
order by ID,EVENT;
```

I know I am missing something, probably a group by. Can you please help me out. I am using ORACLE.

Answer (score 2):

You just need the `MAX` analytic function and partition on `id` and `event`.

```sql
SELECT ID,
       EVENT,
       START_TIME,
       MAX(START_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY id, event) AS latest_start_time
FROM   EVENTS
order by ID,EVENT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   ID,
   EVENT,
   START_TIME,
   MAX(START_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, EVENT) AS latest_start_time
FROM EVENTS
order by ID,EVENT;
```